# Cloning a RAID-1 Array in Linux to a Larger Capacity Drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, clone, raid-1

I have two existing Fonality (Asterisk based) VoIP servers that I would like to upgrade the hard disks on.

Both servers have RAID1 arrays consisting of 2 80GB SATA drives.   Here is the output of `df -h`

```
[rtroiano@pbxtra7004 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2               73G   37G   33G  53% /
/dev/md1               99M   12M   83M  13% /boot
none                  500M     0  500M   0% /dev/shm
```

Here is the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      104320 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      76967296 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      1052160 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Both systems are running CentOS

```
[rtroiano@pbxtra7004 ~]$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.9-89.ELsmp (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc 
version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)) #1 SMP Mon Jun 22 12:32:43 
EDT 2009
```

When I reached out to Fonality support asking them how I should go about upgrading the hard drives to larger capacity drives, they told me that I would need to purchase drives from them.   The problem with that is we only have a support contract for one of the two servers (the primary server).   I do not want to purchase a support contract for our backup server if I do not have to.

I have never attempted to clone a RAID array before.   I was wondering if anyone could suggest a method I could try to clone the existing data onto a larger (1-2TB should be fine) disk without having to purchase drives from Fonality or make it so I have to purchase another support contact for our backup server.

Let me know if you need any additional information, I will be happy to provide any command outputs needed.

Comment: Not exactly your question, but make sure to double check that support contract you have, it may require that any replacement hardware is purchased through Fonality.  It's pretty standard for such a clause to be present in a support contract like that because it lines their pockets while making the support staff's jobs easier (fewer hardware configurations to deal with means simpler support).

Comment: Yeah good suggestion actually.   Knowing Fonality, that is probably the case :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling Fonality and they found a bunch of old phone recordings going back to 2009 that we could delete.  Now we have more than enough space available.